# What does "compression ratio = 4.2x" mean?

Tags: ratio

I have some difficulties in understanding the mean of **compression ratio = 4.2x**. If a 100MB file get compressed with this algorithm, the result will be 420MB? If so, it will not be a good compression algorithm, because the result is bigger than the original file. I think I'm missing something here. Can someone explain me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should mean that the size of the resulting file is $\frac 1{4.2}$ of the original file, so a $100$ MB file becomes $23.8$ MB.  However, such numbers are often in the minds of the company writing the compression software, so you should see if you can find more details.